# MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: spring, maven, jackson

Есть такой класс MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter определенный в Spring 3.
Я перевожу проект на Spring 4 в этом месте в spring-servlet.xml

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>

            <bean id="jsonConverter"
                  class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            </bean>

        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

появляется ошибка

ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.17.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```